# Rendering angular app without html or directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I started to work on existing project writed in angular. What is mysterious for me is that in HTML is not used anything from angular.

```
<div id="chat">
    <div data-id="6863" data-name="patrik.valkovic"></div>
</div>
```

Then is just called bootstrap

```
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('chat'), ['drahak.chat'])
```

Run method of module calls only GET request and connects to socket

```
drahak.chat.run([
'Socket', '$http', 'host', 'port', function (Socket, $http, host, port) {
    $http.get('http://' + host.slice(5) + ':' + port + '/config')
        .then(function (config) {
            return drahak.chat.emoticons = config.data.emoticons;
        });
    return Socket.on('events:batch', EventsBatchCallback);
    }
]);
```

But when I visit this site, it generate while template from separate file.
What is this possible? Is angular responsible for this or is code somewhere else, that i don't find it?

EDIT: Routes are not used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i finally figured it out. In inner div is also "data-token" attribute and "token" directive was registered. I don't realize that angular could also chain with "data-" attribute (without ng-). That directive replace that element with template.